# The way to redirect from Visualforce page to LWC component along with data

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I have a LWC component where I am calling a VF page in an iframe for the payment so when the payment completes it redirects me inside the iframe which I don't want instead it should redirect to LWC component along with some data and from there I want to redirect it.
I have not find anything useful how can I achieve this

Well right now I am redirecting to my VF from LWC component like this:

```
    <template>
           <template if:false = {showPopUp}>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label={payNowText} icon-name="utility:moneybag" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={payByStripe}>
    </lightning-button></template>
<template if:true = {showPopUp}><iframe id="vfFrame" src={vfHost} class="wk-iframe" height="500px" width="770px"></iframe></template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
payByStripe(){
    this.vfHost = 'sandbox_URL/checkoutPayment?orderId='+this.order_id;
    this.showPopUp = true;
}
```

it is redirecting to my VF page and I am able to successfully transact but how can do the reverse. I mean how can I redirect back to my LWC component after successful component.
*The above iframe renders in a modal so when I am trying to redirect it is redirecting me inside the modal not the main component or parent component

Right now what I am trying to do for communication

in my apex

```
public static boolean showAlert{get;set;}
if(statusCode == 200){
        showAlert = true;
    }
```

VF page

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!showAlert}">
            <script>
                var lexOrigin = 'https://fun-java-6633-dev-ed.cs90.my.salesforce.com';
        
                function firetoLWC() {
                    var message = document.getElementById('{!$Component.f1.ordId}').value;
                    console.log('Order ID');
                    console.log(message);
                    window.parent.postMessage(message, lexOrigin);
                }
           </script>
        </apex:outputText>
```

so it should invoke this JS method but it is not invoking what I am doing wrong here

Now in my LWC

```
receivedMessage = '';
error;

// Wire getVFOrigin Apex method to a Property
vfOrigin = "https://fun-java-6633-dev-ed.cs90.my.salesforce.com/apex/checkoutPayment";

handleVFResponse(message) {
    if (message.origin === this.vfOrigin.data) {
        this.receivedMessage = message.data;
        console.log('Fire this');
        console.log(message.data);
    }
}

connectedCallback() {
    try {
        window.addEventListener("message", this.handleVFResponse.bind(this));
        console.log('Order Id = '+this.order_id);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<template if:true={receivedMessage}>
                <p> Message Received from VF = </p>
                <div class="slds-box">
                    <lightning-formatted-text value={receivedMessage}></lightning-formatted-text>
                </div>
                </template>
```

Comment: Where is the redirection logic configured how does the system know to redirect to VF Page?

Comment: Hi Nagendra, could you please see my updated question

Comment: I guess you can create LWC tab or navigatable component and redirect to it. Will it work for you?

Comment: actually I did that, but the client's requirement is different

Comment: Well, I got the answer, I have used window.parent.location.href = "http://www.example.com"; in my VF page and it is redirecting me to the parent component